# Sencha Touch ResumeEvents is a catastrophe

Tags: store, sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha's Ext.data.Store to hold some items.  Right now they come from an xml webservice but that will change to a JSON query.  After adding 500 items calling ResumeEvents on the Store can take 20 seconds!  If I comment the Suspend and ResumeEvents from my code it runs faster.

What gives?  Does the library not combine multiple event notifications, or does is save all of them to send when you call ResumeEvents?

This is not good.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the suspendEvents parameter to `false` to prevent the queuing up of events upon resumeEvents.

```
myApp.myView.suspendEvents(false);
```

This is the description of the parameter in the Sencha docs:

> queueSuspended : Boolean
>
> *Pass as true to queue up suspended events to
>   be fired after the resumeEvents call instead of discarding all
>   suspended events;*